# Magento 2 production mode not set

Tags: magento2.2.2, developer-mode, production-mode

In Magento 2, when I went to change my store mode from **Developer** to **Production** from cmd(putty), it will return one error message

```
Command return non-zero exit code :
```

So how can I fixed it and if possible then please tell me is there anything wrong from our side.

Thanks!

Comment: wich command you have used?

Comment: i have use php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production

Answer (score 1):

First check which mode display

`php bin/magento deploy:mode:show`

production mode

`php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production`

Please Refer this Link

`https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/9202`

`https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10431`

Comment: I have checked but still, it's not working for me. the same error message is displayed. can you please suggest any reference video for fixed this issue.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production
```

Comment: I have try it but error is still show.

Is there any server configuration issue ?

Comment: please send me error description beacause after run this command include comile and static-content deploy ...possible error at setup:di:compile

Answer (score 0):

It may be a file permission issue, so first you have to set the permission of var and pub folders

```
sudo chmod -R 777 var pub
```

Then set the mode as you want.

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production
```